# Upsampling for the whole dataset or for each mini-batch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resampling, smote

I am trying to train my convNet on a very large unbalanced dataset. It will be quite difficult to load the data altogether to memory and do the upsampling on the whole dataset.

Instead, I want to load the data in mini-batches and do the upsampling for each of those mini-batches. Will that be a valid way to do resampling and training?

I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Do you want to use `smote` or repeat minority class as your upsampling method? What framework do you use?

Comment: I am using SMOTE algorithm with imblearn package in Python